# Magento 2 - Order status after shipment and invoice

Tags: sales-order, order-status, magento-2.1.3

I'm using Magento 2.1.3

I would like to change the order status to custom "`waiting for courier`" after shipping and invoice is created instead of "`complete`".

Right now I'm using event "`sales_order_shipment_save_after`" but it's not enough.

Where can I find it?

Comment: For invoice use `sales_order_invoice_save_after`

Comment: Thanks, but I would use new status when invoice and shipping are both created (doesn't matter if invoice or shipping was first). "sales_order_shipment_save_after" and "sales_order_invoice_save_after" I can use separately.

Comment: https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-events.html

Comment: Thanks. I used https://cyrillschumacher.com/magento-2.1-list-of-all-dispatched-events/ But it doesn't looks complete.

Answer (score 2):

For that you do not need development. You can do this in your backend directly:

**Step 1 : Add new status**
 - In `Stores` > `Settings` > `Order Status`
 - `Create new status`
 - Status code : `waiting_for_courier`
 - Status label : `Waiting for courier`
 - `Save status`

**Step 2 : Assign status to state**
 - `Assign Status to State` button
 - Order status : `Waiting for courier`
 - Order state : `Complete`
 - Use Order Status As Default : `Yes` => **important**
 - Visible On Storefront : `Yes`
 - `Save Status Assignment`

With that you defined the `waiting_for_courier` status as the new defaut `complete` state status instead of `complete`.

If you want more informations about status / state management here is a article about that : http://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/manage-order-status-in-magento-2/

Comment: Thanks :) It help me a lot and almost works. There is one problem - I don't want set state complete yet. I need to set state 'complete' after package is delivered to customer.

Comment: What is triggering the change from `waiting for courier` to `complete` ? Is that the shipment is completed ? How do you have this information ?

Comment: Couriers Api provide this information

Comment: In this case you can do this : use my answer solution and then at the API response you can set the `complete` status to the order. Depeding on your other developments but the fact that both of the status are with the state `complete` is not an issue. It is native that Magento set `complete` state when the invoice and shipment are created.

Comment: Is that OK for you ?

Comment: Not at all. I need to change Order's state. I'm not sure it is worth to spend time.

Answer (score 0):

Create around plugin on Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Handler\State:Check method
something like below

```
public function aroundCheck(State $subject, callable $proceed, Order $order)
{
    $shipping = $order->getShippingMethod();
    $needChange = $order->getState() === Order::STATE_PROCESSING && $shipping === Carrier::SHIPPING_CODE; // check if my custom shipping method used
    $result =  $proceed($order);
    if ($order->getState() === Order::STATE_COMPLETE && $needChange) {
        $order->setStatus('my_custom_status_assigned_to_complete_state');
    }

    return $result;
}
```